# Dividend yield for an index

Tags: options, black-scholes, forward, index, dividends

Let's say we want to price an option and so need a dividend yield to plug into Black-Scholes.

We can compute an implied dividend yield for a stock using:

$$F=S_0 e^{(r-d)T}$$

and by isolating for $d$. We can then use this implied dividend in pricing options.

But how do we find the implied dividend yield for an index? E.g. what if we want to price an option on an index, and there are no forwards for that index?

Comment: I suppose you mean no futures contracts trading on that index? Even then, if you have listed (European) options, you can always apply call-put parity: $F(0,T) = K + (C(K,T)-P(K,T))/DF(0,T)$ where $K$ is the strike, $C(.)$ (resp. $P(.)$) European call (resp. put) price struck at $K$ with maturity $T$ and $DF$ the relevant discount factor, i.e. $DF = \exp(R(0,T)T)$. If options are American, things get a little more complicated.

Comment: Right, but what if there are no futures/forwards on that index? That means in your equation the LHS ($$F(0,T)$$) is unknown. So how then do we find C(K,T)? Can we use a composite of the individual forwards on the components of the index. I.e. back out a weighted average of the dividend yields implied by the individual forwards on stocks in the index?

Comment: To be clear, I'm assuming we want to price C(K,T) and so we don't yet have that.

Comment: Forecasts of upcoming dividends from companies in an index can and are being made.

Comment: Ok. So are you saying that the implied dividend yield we can plug into Black-Scholes is a weighted average of the dividend yields for the stocks in that index?

Comment: I see, maybe you should add that in your question to be clear. Yes, you could see the index as a basket of equities: $S_t = \sum_{i=1}^N w_i S_t^{(i)}$ (weighted sum of its constituents, the weights $w_i$ given by the index construction rules). You would then have that the index forward is the weighted sum of the individual forwards. This remains an approximation though because in practice the weights of an index are not constant (composition reshuffling). Also, you should be careful regarding 'compo' effects (e.g. constituents denominated in a different currency than that of the index).

Comment: Ok, so I can go ahead and do that then. Thanks a lot! Any chance you know of a good resource on this to read up on? Or something I can reference as a source to back up my claim that I can find dividend yield for an index this way?

Comment: No I have no reference, sorry. But everything boils down to the modelling assumption: $S_t =\sum_{i=1}^N w_i S_t^{(i)}$. If you can write that, then you're fine. Indeed, the forward is an expectation under $\Bbb{Q}$ and since the expectation operator is linear you'll get: $F(0,T) = \sum_{i=1}^N w_i F(0,T)^{(i)}$. Our starting equation is certainly true for the spot price of an index. However, this may not be a good representation of the future price of an index given the reshuffling risk (e.g. how can you be sure component $k$ will still be in the index in $T=5Y$ for instance?).

Comment: Thank you. As a final broader question, do you think that's how options on the HYG ETF are priced? That analysts use the process you outlined above to get an implied dividend yield?

Comment: Or I guess more generally options on the SPY? Do analysts use the straightforward method you just outlined?

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I just came across the Black model (as opposed to the Black Scholes model). It seems that options on bonds are slightly different. Still unsure about options on bond indices though...